# Django Model Query (Getting Categories based on posts)

Tags: python, django, model

Please I need help with a django model query.
I am working on a blog app, with a model for posts and a model for categories.
In my categories page I want to show all my categories but with a single post from each of those categories.
e.g
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0YpS.png)
I want a card with a single post from each category
I tried running a loop but I'm getting confused
Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdE2H.png)
I tried running the loop like this but it brings no results in the template

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `Post` can only be associated with one `PostCategory`, I recommend querying the `Post` model and using `distinct()` to fetch one post for each category:

```
posts = Post.objects.distinct('category')
```

If you want to order the queryset by category name and select the newest post in each category, you could do something like (assuming your `Post` model has a `created` timestamp or something similar):

```
posts = Post.objects.distinct('category__name').order_by('category__name', '-created')
```

If you do *not* want to order the results on the page by category, use `sorted()` to manipulate the queryset:

```
posts = sorted(Post.objects.distinct('category'), key=lambda p: p.created, reverse=True)
```

The above will produce a list (not a queryset), with one post per category, sorted newest post to oldest post.